# Using jawin instead of wmic

Tags: java, windows

Ok i try it again

I can run the command:
`wmic product where name="my application" get installLocation`

JAWIN seems to me like a possibility to avoid Runtime.getRuntime.exe solutions
Does anybody allready worked with jawin to connect to the WMI and find out the InstallLocation of an application? I do not want to read any RegKeys but check how to get this information over WMI.

Thanks for any answer..

Comment: Why bother? How often are you going to run this wmic command? Once per program invocation? It's not a bottleneck. Not worth even thinking about.

Comment: This command will run everytime the user starts a given application. I need the java code to find out where the InstallLocation is, becouse the path is different on the workstations. This path is necessary for other actions. Do you suggest another solution?